# Is it a bad idea to create directories in the constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor, directory, installation

At first it seemed natural - if a set of directories didn't exist, the object that works on them wouldn't be able to fulfill its contracts.  So in the constructor I have some logic to check if some directories exist and create them if not.  Though not actually a singleton yet, this object is used like one.

Is the constructor a bad place for this kind of setup logic?

**Background**
The class is called FileGetter. It abstracts getting particular files from a remote server, extracting them, and preparing the files and placing them in another directory where a second class will be filesystemwatching/processing the data.

Comment: What is the purpose of the object?

Comment: The constructor should do the smallest amount of work to insure the object is functional. Doing more leads to a myriad of problems, performance can take a serious hit if you make constructors overly  complex, memory consumption (Create an array of object), debugging (When the constructor fails), etc... Even if it's a singleton, these things can come back to bite you later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From an [Inversion of Control or Dependency Inversion perspective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control), yes, it's incorrect.

You state that the object that works on the directories couldn't do it's work if they didn't exist.  I'd abstract out the providing and the check/creation of the directories to another abstraction and then pass the implementation of that abstraction to your object.

Then, your object would simply get the directories from this abstraction and continue from there.

As an example, here's what I mean.  First, there is the abstraction of the directory provider, like so:

```
public interface IDirectoryProvider
{
    // Gets the full paths to the directories being worked on.
    IEnumerable<string> GetPaths();
}
```

Then there is the implementation.

```
public sealed class DirectoryProvider
{
    public DirectoryProvider(IEnumerable<string> directories)
    {
        // The validated directories.
        IList<string> validatedDirectories = new List<string>();

        // Validate the directories.
        foreach (string directory in directories)
        {
            // Reconcile full path here.
            string path = ...;

            // If the directory doesn't exist, create it.
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

            // Add to the list.
            validatedDirectories.Add(path);
        }
    }

    private readonly IEnumerable<string> _directories;

    public IEnumerable<string> GetPaths()
    {
         // Just return the directories.
         return _directories;
    }
}
```

Finally, there is your class which processes the directories, which would look like this:

```
public sealed DirectoryProcessor
{
    public DirectoryProcessor(IDirectoryProvider directoryProvider)
    {
        // Store the provider.
        _directoryProvider = directoryProvider;
    }

    private readonly IDirectoryProvider _directoryProvider;

    public void DoWork()
    {
        // Cycle through the directories from the provider and
        // process.
        foreach (string path in _directoryProvider.GetPaths())
        {
            // Process the path
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At the risk of sounding snarky, at some point the object needs to do actual *work*. The OP's question could just as easily *be* about the implementation of your IOC abstraction.

Comment: @Adam that's a great point but in my case the current design isn't from the IOC perspective

Comment: Generally this is a good way to do this.  I tend to agree the directory necessity should be extracted so it doesn't bring its baggage into the processor class.  For instance I was thinking the provider should be singleton-ish so it just does directory checking/creation once.  So with the extra abstraction I get cheaply constructed objects that also know their contracts, and dependencies don't don't infect the class signature with their requirements, which hides complexity.  TRIPLE WIN!

Comment: That's too bad I can't edit comments more than 5 min later...  Anyway the only thing that bothers me about DI is the extra code in callers.  It seems to add complexity for consumers - but in this case a worthwhile trade-off.

Answer (score 5):

I would say that it depends. In general it's a good idea to make object construction as cheap as possible; that is, have the constructors contain the least possible amount of logic. That speaks against creating directories in the constructor. If, on the other hand, the object really cannot operate at all without the directories, it might be a good idea to fail as early as possible (for instance in case the directories cannot be created for some reason). This could speak for creating them in the constructor.

Personally I would probably lean towards *not* creating them in the constructor, but instead have each method that needs them call some method that creates the directories, if that is not already done.

Answer (score 2):

You could either put the logic to handle the lack of folders in the class itself or in every piece of code that will consume that class.

The choice, really, is up to you.  If you choose to put it inside the class itself, the constructor is a perfectly fine place for it, as a constructor is there to "setup" the class and all the things that it needs to function.

Comment: I would definitely prefer to hide these kinds of things at the class level.

Comment: I prefer to code classes etc. as I would an API, meaning the consuming code should have to do as little as possible to actually *use* the class.  It's nice to make classes simple and concise, but if you have a complicated code block rife with logic just to call `MyClass.GetFile()` I'm of the feeling that something is amiss.

Comment: Excellent point - I tend to want to design from this perspective first.  The most important thing we do in programming is to hide complexity.  I do think you can strike a balance though - where callers don't get super complicated but you still get to divide things into many classes and then conquer.

Answer (score 1):

I like [casperOne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666392/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-create-directories-in-the-constructor/5666433#5666433). However I would consider following stuff:

1. How often is this distinct object created.
2. How many directories are being created.
3. How often will the constructor be used to create a directory
4. Will you need feedback about the status of a directory
5. Will you need feedback about the reason why a directory was not present or any other error.
6. and last but not least: is it worth the effort to think about another way?

Depending on those questions you might realize that this is just a situation called once in the lifetime of an object. It should not fail and if it does something else is going wrong completely. So I would decide to keep the logic where it is.

If you have time and you consider to extend the program, use the class elsewhere or maybe create a lot more directories it might be worth to create a directory provider as described by casperOne. If more than one directories are being created, more than once, for instance at each start of the program and/or you have the possibility to reuse the code and be as flexible as possible ... then I would strongly recommend to use a directory provider, thus making the object more flexible and reducing the chance to create a SPOF inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I think a constructor is there for exactly this kind of thing?

Comment: That was my thought initially but I'm second-guessing it.